# Using both ACRA error reporting and Google's Dev Console?

Tags: android, acra

I'm curious if I start using ACRA error reporting will error reports still show up in the Developer Console?  If not, is there a way to allow for both?  I'd like to be able to log into my dev console and see any new reports then go check the ACRA spreadsheet for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually recommend that you use [bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com) in conjunction with acra. It has a really nice interface in my opinion and you can use acra fields and whatnot.

Comment: Funny that this is tagged as an answer even if it does not answer the question. Anyway, I'd like to know the answer too becase no crash reports are shown in Developer Console for one project of ours where we use ACRA.